# Does a xenomorphs acid blood make it vulnerable to water, or any other base/buffer solution?

Tags: aliens, xenomorph, biology

For humans, a sudden change of blood pH from 7.4 to say 7.5 would be quite significantly harmful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalosis this is because of all the highly specialised proteins in the human body have developed for a specific pH and their complex 3D structures are damaged by Acids and alkali. This is also the case for most animal species on earth.

given that the Xenomorphs blood Ph is EXTREMELY low would it be possible to disturb one's homeostasis and give them Alkalosis by drawing them into a large body of water (or base or buffer solution if you happen to have a large volume of that around I guess) and draw blood letting the water dilute the acid blood raising the Ph enough to do a great deal of harm to the Xenomorph, preferably killing them.

I know that predicting Alien biology is always problematic (though it is worth noting Xenomorphs do have some weird genetic herritage with humans if you believe Prometheus). So:

A. Is there any case in the Aliens "expanded universe" of someone using a tactic like this?

B. are there any known extremophiles capable of withstanding large internal Ph ranges?

Comment: They can swim just fine; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv7_7dSbaOk

Comment: @Valorum but can they swim in water with a crapload of baking soda dissolved in it?

Comment: @Forral  - I demand you go find out and come back and tell us.

Comment: You're assuming that a xenomorph with intact skin in a body of water would have its blood pH affected by some kind of osmosis or some other mechanism where the water penetrates their skin, which wouldn't necessarily happen at all.

Comment: Its worth noting i did mention drawing blood in my question, though enjoying the tangent anyway

Comment: I know it's not a full answer, but I think it's worth noting: The closest example I know of is that Predators' blood was established to have a neutralizing effect on the Xenomorphs' corrosive blood. I haven't read "Prey" however, so I don't know how violent such a process might be. It'd be interesting to see the Predators using a blowgun with darts filled with their own blood. http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja_blood

Comment: “drawing them into a large body of water... and draw blood” — could work! You give it a go, I’ll observe from a ship in orbit that has nuclear missiles for no particular reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just "bleeding" wouldn't necessarily do it - after all, if you have a cut on your finger you can dip it into a container of alcohol.  Not pleasant, not gonna kill you either.  Also, the circulation of the blood would be more likely to be pushing blood out and not letting water enter the circulation system.

As far as sending your xenomorph for a swim in a pool that is very basic in pH that wouldn't cause any extra issues that even a mostly pH neutral thing would experience - alkalines can burn/dissolve matter somewhat like acids can.  In fact, a new thing for "cremation" is alkaline hydrolysis where the body is broken down by a very high pH solution.

**A. Is there any case in the Aliens "expanded universe" of someone using a tactic like this?**

Not sure on the Aliens universe, but fanfiction writer AA Pessimal addressed how the Assassin's Guild of Ank-Morpork dealt with a xeno, involving a container surrounded by alkaline salts.  Takes up a good part of his "Slipping Between Worlds" - https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6159511/1/Slipping-Between-Worlds  If you like the Discworld, he writes very well and writes good stuff.  If you don't like the Discworld, I don't know what is wrong with you :)

Comment: I do indeed like discworld

Comment: @Ummdustry - you are gonna LOVE Pessimal's stuff then. GNU Terry Pratchett.  Today is 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

The *Because Science* channel took a look at the acidity of Xenomorph blood and tried to access what its acidity was. You can see it here:

Considering the **extreme level** of acidity, it has to be a chemical close to our beyond fluorine. Simply mixing it with water would sooner [if the science is to be believed] it to explode as opposed to causing it to be neutralize. However, this isn't the case, as we know the Xenomorphs are essentially a biological weapon made to adapt to various environments. As water is one of the most common elements and environments on several planets, they have been made to survive in it, some *specifically so,* as we see here:

Even the non-specialized Xenomorphs can move easily in water with no ill effects, as seen in the canon movie **Alien: Resurrection** right here:

I personally am not versed enough in the bio-chemistry to offer an exact explanation for this, but the mere fact that it has been shown that they *Can* swim in water would pretty much indicate that alkalosis isn't a problem for them in a Ph neutral substance like water. As to how or why this can be, I can only offer a rudimentary theory of their bodies having either a natural protective capacity to such elements, *or* some kind of natural adaptation effect which shields them from it.

The latter makes sense; after all, remember that they xenomorphs tend to inherit traits from whatever species they lay eggs in, and *most* living creatures that we know of actually *need* water to survive, or even *begin* life.